# Putting names in an electrical component terminal

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to know how to put a name in a component terminal, in this case a diode.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}  
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contenido} 
\begin{document}   

\maketitle 

\begin{figure}[h]\centering 
\begin{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=0.85, bipoles/diode/width=0.85,}
\draw (10,0) to[diode] (15,0);

\end{circuitikz} 
\caption{Símbolo del Diodo}
\end{figure}
```

I would like to have the text in here, I believe that is by declaring nodes and then giving a name to does nodes but I'm not sure.

[image: electrical component]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, nodes can do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}   
\begin{figure}[h]\centering 
\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=0.85, bipoles/diode/width=0.85,}
 \draw (10,0)  node[above right,align=center]{some\\ text} to[diode]
  (15,0) node[above left,align=center]{more\\ text} ;
\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm,pin distance=15mm,
 every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt,stealth-,bend left},
 every pin/.style={align=center}]
  \draw (10,0)  coordinate[pin=above right:{some\\ text}] to[diode]
    (15,0) coordinate[pin={[pin edge={bend right}]above left:{more\\ text}}] ;
\end{scope}

\end{circuitikz} 
\caption{S\'imbolo del Diodo.}
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

[image]